# Scrape website and insert a table into my own HTML document

Tags: javascript, html, web-scraping

I want to be able to extract a table from a website and put it into my own HTML page. For example, I want the information contained in the table class 'tbbox' on this website: http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/astronomy.html?n=24 inserted into my own HTML page. I want to avoid executing any kind of server side code like PHP. Perhaps use JavaScript for this? All the examples I have come across so far only provide details on how to extract the information into a CSV or text file.

Sorry if this question seems a bit vague but I know very little about how javascript is run on webpages and am not a web developer. I am just trying to setup a dashboard for personal use that will extract astronomical information from various websites into a single page, which I can open to find information at a glance.

Thanks for taking the time.

Comment: [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy)

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do has nothing to do with web-scraping. The problem you have can easily be solved with an `<iframe>` on your page that fetches the desired info from another source on load. Here is a reference that might help you with that: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/present/frames.html

NOTE! Only display this information on your site if you are allowed to do so!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was looking through the link you have provided, but I see no mention of how to extract just one table from another website. An iframe, as I understand it, will allow me to display the contents of the entire target page within a frame in my page.